# Is it a problem if several load bearing studs aren't plumb?

Tags: walls, studs

To make a long story short, please check the picture that I took. There are 2 vertical load bearing studs are not parallel.  The contractor moved one of the studs to the left at the bottom.

[image]

Is that OK to be like that?  Or it will be a potential problem in the future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say its fine, it is strapped to prevent lateral movement, but i am not an engineer. For peace of mind you could just put another stud in, bottom up against the other and use a level to make it plum and true. Toe nail in place. Sleep well.

Comment: I'd take a big hammer and whack the top of the stud over to match the bottom before I'd put more lumber in. Toenail the top. Also, I believe that strapping is for the ducts, not the framing.

Comment: @isherwood The straps may be for the ducts but they do serve to limit movement of the studs. I would not whack the top of the stud over because that would leave the double top plate hanging unsupported- ish with a joist  above not properly supported.

Comment: You say "several", but only show us one. Is this representative of the lot, or did you get carried away somewhere?

Comment: The leaning stud I'm looking at needs to be moved _away_ from the gap in the plates. The distance it needs to be moved wouldn't cause a support problem for the joist above.

Comment: Alaska Man and I were addressing two different things, Derek. He's right about the unsupported plates, and _that_ is what you need to address with your builder.

Answer (score 9):

While the world won't end if it stays, the top of the stud should also be moved. It's easy to do and lazy not to. There are a few reasons:

- When locating the stud later for mounting photos or whatever a person would be led astray after finding the stud at one height and then trying to hit it at another.
- Any electrical or other hardware attached to it will also be (slightly) askew.
- Drywall hangers might be frustrated if their sheet ends on that stud or their screws don't hit in the field as expected.
- It's technically less strong at a slant, though practically speaking it's not a problem.
- It looks shoddy. No contractor I'd hire would leave it leaning simply as a matter of pride.

**More concerning are the places where joists rest on unsupported plates** (due to the plates being cut completely out). Studs should be added against the duct cutouts to support those areas.

Comment: What about the end of the double top plate that is supporting the end of a joist? I think it would better to add a stud rather than have that top plate/joist slightly cantilevered unsupported.  No?

Comment: You're right, but that wasn't the question. The issue you raise has to do with the plates being cut out. I'll revise to mention that.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Good eye. But I think there are three joists supported on cantilevered top plates: the one between the ducts and two more to the right of them. (I'm giving a pass to the other joist between the ducts since it is almost on top of a stud.) It seems the HVAC contractor has made a real mess of things and there are substantial framing repairs needed.